# how to check if a value exisist in a list with jquery

Tags: jquery, list, drag-and-drop

I have two columns between which I can drag and drop list-items. Left I have just one full employeelist, right I have multiple lists to assign a member to a function.

To make sure I can drag a member multiple times from left to right (each employee can have multiple functions), I use cloneNode. Now I am looking for a way to prevent dropping the same employee twice in a list.
I tried this, but unsuccesful:

```
    if (dropToID == "#lmn") {
        if (($("#lmn li[value=" + data + "]").length) != 0) {
            $(dropToID).append(document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true));            
            $("#hiddenValueMember"+data).attr("name", "selectedLMN[]");
            save();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `$("#hiddenValueMember"+data)`?

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi at first I just used an li with a value. But when dragging it seemed that I couldn't get the right drop-id. I will try again after I get this problem working.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I forgot to say that I use that hidden member to save the value. It must get it working with the li-value as well, I suppose...

Answer (score 1):

I've just created a little example how this can be done: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/matthias_h/pwfo4m82/)

Whenever an employee is dropped at a task, the employee-id is added to an array that is stored as data-attribute on the task. In case an employee already is assigned to the task, he/she can't be added again.
This is no full version, I did not take care about removing an employee from an assigned task and adjust the array accordingly, it's just an example how to solve the issue with avoiding to assign the same employee to the same task twice. In case this would work for your requirements, it shouldn't be a problem to adjust it to work with your already existing employee and task lists.
In the Fiddle I kept the console.log messages so it's easier to check what's already in the different arrays / data-attributes.

```
$(function () {
  $(".people").draggable({
    containment: ".container",
    helper: 'clone'
});

$("#tasks li").droppable({
    accept: '.people',
    greedy: true,
    drop: function (e, ui) {
        var newOne = ui.draggable.clone().removeAttr("style"),
            jobId = $(this).attr("id"),
            peopleId = newOne.attr("id");

        if (false === arrayHelper(jobId, peopleId)) {
            alert(peopleId + " already assigned to " + jobId);
        } else {
            $(this).find("ul").append(newOne);
        }

        arrayHelper(jobId, peopleId);
      }
   });

});

function arrayHelper(task, people) {

  if ($("#" + task).data("people") == "")
  {
    holder = [];
    holder.push("#" + people);
    $("#" + task).data("people", holder);
  }
  else
  {
     if ($.inArray("#" + people, holder) != -1)
     {
        return false;
     }
     else
     {
        holder.push("#" + people);
        $("#" + task).data("people", holder);
     }
   }
}
```

HTML for this example:

```
<div class="container">
   <ul id="tasks">
      <li id="task1" data-people="">typing
        <ul></ul>
      </li>
      <li id="task2" data-people="">phone
        <ul></ul>
      </li>
      <li id="task3" data-people="">letters
        <ul></ul>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <div class="divide"></div>
   <ul id="people">
      <li class="people" id="people1">peter</li>
      <li class="people" id="people2">paul</li>
      <li class="people" id="people3">mary</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```